# Modify codeigniter image class to allow setting of background color

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the codeigniter image class to resize and crop images to specific sizes. If the source image has a different aspect ratio that prevents it from being set to the size I want I pad the image adding space until it fits. The problem is I need to set this color to white. The test image is black and I suspect the color it chooses is arbitrary. I am thinking the core image library needs to be modified but would love a non hacking way. Please help. Here is my code for reference. Obviously I am passing parameters to it, it should be pretty obvious.

```
copy($row['photo'],$new_filename);  
$this->CI->load->library('image_lib'); 
if ($row['width']>$device_params['width'] || $row['height']>$device_params['height']) {
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $new_filename;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['quality'] = '40%'; 
    if ($scale) {
        $device_params['height'] = ($scale / 100) * $device_params['height'];
        $device_params['width'] = ($scale / 100) * $device_params['width'];
    }
    $config['height'] = $device_params['height'];
    $config['width'] = $device_params['width'];
    $config['master_dim'] = 'height';
    if ($row['width']<$row['height']) {
        $config['rotation_angle'] = '270';
        $config['master_dim'] = 'height';
        if (strtolower(substr($new_filename,-3))=='jpg') {
            $this->CI->image_lib->rotate();
        }
    } else {

    }

    $this->CI->image_lib->initialize($config); 

    $this->CI->image_lib->resize(); 
    $this->CI->image_lib->clear();
    unset($config);
}       
if ($device_params['crop']) {

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    //$config['library_path'] = '/usr/bin/';
    $config['source_image'] = $new_filename;
    $size = getimagesize($new_filename);
    //var_dump($size);
    $x_axis = $size[0]/2-($device_params['width']/2);
    $y_axis = $size[1]/2-($device_params['height']/2);
    //echo $x_axis.'-'.$y_axis;
    //die();
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config['height'] = $device_params['height'];
    $config['width'] = $device_params['width'];
    $config['y_axis'] = $y_axis;
    $config['x_axis'] = $x_axis;
    $config['master_dim'] = 'auto';
    $this->CI->image_lib->initialize($config); 
    if ( ! $this->CI->image_lib->crop())
    {
        $data['output']['status'] = 0;
        $data['output']['message'] = $this->CI->image_lib->display_errors();
    }

}
```

Comment: another approach - instead of padding the image  - would it be easier to overlay the image - on top of a white image? that way you could have white images that were always the correct size.

Comment: Would I then merge the two to make one final image?